# exchange get-distributiongroup powershell issue

Tags: powershell

I need to add a member to about 50 distribution groups. I have the list of groups in "display name" format. According to documentation the -identity parameter of get-distributiongroup takes pipeline input and displayname is an accepted form of identity. The code below works for about 7 groups in the file but not the rest because it can't be found.

```
get-content c:\groups.txt | get-distributiongroup
```

If I type the following code for those groups that didn't work in the above code it does work!

```
get-distributiongroup GroupNameThatDidntWorkBefore
```

So not sure why it won't find the name from the list but will find it when I type it out. It's literally the same name. I made sure of this by copying & pasting one of the names from the list.

Does anyone know if the input for identity tries one type of valid value and then fails without trying the other supported values? Can this be changed? Why would it accept the value when entered manually but not from pipeline?

Ultimately I would like to get the following code to work.

```
get-content c:\groups.txt | get-distributiongroup | add-distributiongroupmember username
```

But I can't move on to the third set in the code until I get the second set to work. Thanks.

Comment: Does your input file have extra spaces at the beginning or end of any of its lines?

Comment: I did check for extra spaces just to be sure and they do not. I can even see when I get the error that it shows no extra spaces in beginning or end of name.

Comment: I've also just made a text file with one of the group names giving me issues and made sure to type it correctly and it can't be found. It will find the group name if I use its samaccountname or DN. Just not display name.

Comment: Special characters can also case trouble if different when typed vs. encoding in an input file. In any case I would recommend using sAMAccountName or distinguished name to avoid problems.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Some type of special and unseen character must be the issue. After typing a few of the names that don't work from the old file to a new file I can get the command to work without issues. It's a weird issue since I copied this list to a notepad file and that normally removes any special formatting. Wished I could tell what was difference since it's literally identical to my eyes. Yes, samaccountname / DN would be better but I was only given displayname and can't query the other attributes with displayname that is not formatted correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: You can get the DN from groups' display names using the AD cmdlets: `Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(displayName=_group's display name_)" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName | Out-File NewInputFile.txt` (or something similar).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I can get the DN from displayname. What I was saying was that with the way it's currently formatted I would have to retype all the displaynames to get it to work. Otherwise with the formatting that they currently have the names won't be found as with the original issue. We ended up just doing it manually since I had spent way too long trying to get the script working and retyping the names would have added more total time vs doing it manually . Thanks again.